# Java generic type arguments

Tags: java, generics

I have a method which takes a `List<?>` as an argument.

```
public static String method(List<?> arg){
     // Do something based on type of the list
}

//I call the method as below
List<ClassA> listA = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
List<ClassB> listB = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
method(listA);
method(listB);
```

In `method`, how do I know if `arg` is a `List` of `ClassA` or a `List` of `ClassB`?

Comment: Declaring the parameter type as `<?>` means exactly that you're not interested in the actual type.

Comment: I used if(arg.get(0) instanceof ClassA) // do something ....
And I am getting intended results. Bt not sure if that would be the right way to do so, from the replies here.

Comment: You could do that even if you weren't using generics (just remove the <?> to demonstrate this). The point of generics is to make it so you don't have to use instanceof or worry about unsafe casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an answer by the user called [Romain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223339/romain)  " If you use < ?>, you mean you aren't going to use the parametrized type anywhere. Either go to the specific type (in your case it seems List< String>) or to the very generic List< Object>  "

Also, I believe that if you use the question mark the compiler wont catch type mismatches until runtime (reified; p.119 of Effective Java), bypassing erasure, and effectively elimating the benefit you get from using generic types???

TO answer the question of the questioner:  if you use List< Object> and then try to cast it to A or to B , possibly using instanceOf , that might be a way to tell what it is.  I bet there is a better way to do it than that though.

Comment: +1 for the OP is _effectively eliminating the benefit you get from using generic types_

Comment: <?> means "I'm not using generics but I want to get rid of the compiler warning."

Comment: -1 because this answer encourages bad coding practice. Defining a method that takes a generic type argument is the appropriate way to do this - it gives you type safety and does not require messy casting. See answer by jahroy.

Answer (score 28):

Technically speaking, you ***CAN*** use `instanceof` to check if an object is a certain type.

However... That's ***NOT*** a good idea.

The way you've declared your method, it can accept a List of any type, so it isn't necessarily going to be A or B.

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but you probably should make your method generic.

You can do so like this:

```
public static <T> String method(List<T> arg) {
    // We now know that the type of the list is T, which is
    // determined based on the type of list passed to this
    // method.  This would demonstrate the point better if
    // the return type was T, but I'm leaving the return type
    // as String, because that's what your code returns.
}
```

---

**Here's a better example**:

If you want to create a generic method that returns the first element of a list, you would do it like this:

```
public static <T> T firstElement(List<T> theList) {
    if (theList == null) {
        return null;
    }
    T objectOfTypeT = theList.get(0);
    return objectOfTypeT;
}
```

Note that the return type is now `T`.

Because we made this method generic, it can return the same type that is used in the List.

You would typically just return `theList.get(0)`, but I added a line to make the purpose of generics more obvious.

**Explanation of syntax:**

- The `<T>` indicates that this method takes one type parameter named T.
- The `T` that immediately follows is the return type (just like you would normally return String, Integer, etc...).
- The `T` in the List parameter is how the compiler knows what the heck a `T` is.

This allows the compiler to say: "*This method expects something of type T.  Oh look... The list is also of type T.  If somebody passes a list of Strings to this method, than T must be a String.  If somebody passes a list of Integers to this method, T must be an Integer.*"

In contrast, your method can **only** return a String and it has no idea what type is used in the List.

---

Also...

If A and B both extend the same class, named TheParentClass, you could declare your method like this:

```
public static String method(List<? extends TheParentClass> arg)
```

That way, you'd know a little more about the possible types of your parameter (and can benefit from compile time type checking).

Comment: That last example you gave of "? extends TheParentClass" is probably how the ? was "meant" to be used.  Allowing the use of a ? without the extends bit is, like David Mason suggests, bad practice but legal.  I think jahroy should be awarded the answer to this question rather than me because he nailed it.