# Java Generics Return Type Syntax

Tags: java, list, generics

I am trying to learn how to code a method to return a List of objects of unknown type. I have come across this example:

```
public <T> List<T> list(Class<T> c, List<Object> objectList){        
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();       
    for (Object o : objectList){
        T t = c.cast(o);
        list.add(t);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Why is the return type `<T> List<T>` instead of simply `List<T>`?

Comment: Because it's a generic method.

Comment: The first `<T>` declares the type parameter. With just `List<T>`, an actual class with the name `T` must exist.

Comment: Of specific value, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149196/1079354).

Comment: Just for the record: you could still accept an answer ... even when the answer got closed. So consider doing that later ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `list` method has a generic type argument of its own. `<T>` introduces this type:

```
<T> List<T> list(Class<T> c, List<Object> objectList)
 ^       ^             ^
 |       +-------------+----- Use generic type
 +--------------------------- Introduce generic type argument for use in the method
```

The initial `<T>` is not required when generic methods use type arguments of their enclosing class.

Comment: I like your ascii art .. p1 for that!

Answer (score 4):

That is **not** the return type:

```
public <T> List<T>
```

This simply means: T is a generic parameter *just* for this one method!

You can place type parameters on a *class* **or** just on methods. You see - when all your other methods do need a generic type ... then you might only use it for a single method like this.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for further reading!

Answer (score 0):

`<T>` isn't a return type.  It defines the type of that generic method. Have a look into the parameter list you also find a class with a generic typeinfo

Answer (score 0):

The return type IS `List<T>`.

`<T>` is the "template"/generic declaration : where you declare your generic types. I don't think it is an actual part of the result type (could be wrong on this).